# How to rename files in Google Script conditioned to something

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a script to rename files in a Google Drive but it is not working. In particular, I want to erase the last character of the file name and set this new name as the file name.

```
function re_name() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderId");
  var files =  folder.getFiles();
  var date = new Date("August 29, 2018");
  while(files.hasNext()){
    var aux = files.next();
    if(aux.getDateCreated() == date ){
      aux.setName(aux.getName().replace(".s", ""))
    }
  }
```

Also, I'm not sure if replace() that exists in java can be used in Google Script.

But even if it is not the case to use replace() I can't seem to make modifications an follows:

```
aux.setName(aux.getName() + ".f")
```

Please help to find the mistake or else I would very much appreciate an alternative method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function re_name() {
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById("folderId");
  var files=folder.getFiles();
  var date=new Date("August 29, 2018");
  while(files.hasNext()){
   var aux=files.next();
   if(aux.getDateCreated() == date){
     aux.setName(aux.getName().slice(0,-1));//remove last character
     //aux.setName(aux.getName().replace(/s$/,'');//replace last s
     //aux.setName(aux.getName().replace(/\w$/,'');//replace last word character[A-Za-z0-9_]
   }
 }
}
```

- [JavaScript Slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)
- [JavaScript Replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [Regular Expression Reference](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)

Comment: Great, it worked. I think the problem was that i wasn´t using regular expressions in the replace function. Thanks Cooper